# WCF Project type differences

Tags: web-services, wcf

I'm working on few WCF tutorials and I would like to understand the difference between WCF Service Library, WCF Service Application and WCF Workflow Service Application.

Do you have any examples on when I should use service library and service application?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Service Application hosts the service directly in IIS.
WCF Service Library you have to handle the hosting yourself.
WCF Workflow Service Application does the same as the WCF Service Application except for Workflow services (WF).

Comment: Sorry, but as a newbie to WCF and WF, I'm gonna need more info.  What if I just want a cloud-hosted C# webservice (Sharepoint, Amazon or Azure?) that updates my database every time I call it?